# State Ned Conjecture using logic notation

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

How can the following conjecture be expressed using logic notation:

*"Every sufficiently large integer is an integer that can be expressed as the sum of five primes, with no prime appearing **more than twice**."*

I know how to express "every sufficiently large integer is an integer that can be expressed as the sum of five primes," but what I don't know is how to express "with no prime appearing **more than twice**."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what's below '$\land$' has priority over '$\implies$'.$$\exists n\in \Bbb Z\forall k\in \Bbb Z(k\ge n\implies \exists m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4, m_5\in \Bbb P\color{red}(k=\sum \limits_{i=1}^5(m_i)\, \land \,\\\exists i,j\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}\exists x\in \Bbb P\color{green}(i\neq j \,\land\, m_i=x\land m_j=x\implies \\\forall r\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}\color{orange}(r\neq i\land r\neq j\implies m_r\neq x\color{orange}) \color{green})\color{red})).$$

Translating back to words one gets: there exists an integer $n$ such that for all integers $k$ which are greater than $n$, it is true that there exist 'five' prime numbers $m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4, m_5$ such that $k=m_1+m_2+m_3+m_4+m_5$ and if $x$ is equal to $m_i,m_j$ for some $i,j\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ with $i\neq j$, then $x$ isn't any of the other aforementioned primes.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce that expression?

Comment: @AdamCart I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to saying that no three of the five prime elements are the same. Do you know how to say that? (It may be a little long, but it shouldn't be complicated)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but the OP is asked to translate this particular sentence and not an equivalent one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting. Saying that no prime appears more than twice is the same as saying that no prime appears three times.

Comment: If one is asked to translate $\text{If John goes to the beach, then it isn't raining.}$, one shouldn't translate $\text{If it is raining, then John doesn't go to the beach}$. They are equivalent, but they are not the same statement. Sintactically they are different, even though semantically they assert the same thing.

Comment: However, due to the lack of rigour of natural language, I think your suggestion might be acceptable on second thought.